# Trouble with Audio and vcr/usb capture device

Tags: sound

Im trying to use a analog to usb capture device to digitize old VHS tapes.  I got the video working,  but not the audio.

ubuntu: 22.04  5.19.0-35-generic

device: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08C9T5M37?psc=1&ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08C9T5M37)

dmesg:

```
[Mar21 09:57] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 19
[Mar21 09:58] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 21 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.149974] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=534d, idProduct=0021, bcdDevice= 1.21
[  +0.000013] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[  +0.000006] usb 1-2: Product: AV TO USB2.0
[  +0.000004] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: MACROSIL
[  +0.001204] usb 1-2: Found UVC 1.00 device AV TO USB2.0 (534d:0021)
[  +0.000445] usb 1-2: UVC non compliance - GET_DEF(PROBE) not supported. Enabling workaround.
[  +0.101934] usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
```

aplay -l:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC887-VD Digital [ALC887-VD Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 10: HDMI 4 [HDMI 4]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

Comment: Do you know for a fact that this device works with Ubuntu? Does it need drivers?

Comment: 100% sure?  no.  I did check the reviews on it and several mentioned they were able to get it working with linux.   I dont know if it requires drivers specifically

Comment: Version of Linux and in what year?

Comment: I put that info in my question.  ubuntu 22.04  um year is 2023...

Comment: No the year of the reviews.

Comment: oh..sorry  2021  and 22

Comment: So they predate 22.04 LTS and you never said what Linux they said it works on. I suspect the device is simply too old for this newest version of Ubuntu or maybe any version of Ubuntu.

Comment: actually....got it working.   there was an issue in my config with OBS studio.  the output wasn't set correctly.   Working now.

Answer (score 0):

config error in OBS studio.   User error

Comment: Not an answer please document the exact error and what you did to fix it to help future users of the site.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same device and can capture audio and video from a Sony Hi8 Camcorder using the script below:

#!/bin/sh

videodevice="/dev/video0"
alsadevice="hw:CARD=MS210x,DEV=0"

gst-launch-1.0 -q v4l2src device="$videodevice" do-timestamp=true norm="PAL" pixel-aspect-ratio=1 
! video/x-raw,format=YUY2,framerate=25/1,width=720,height=576 
! queue max-size-buffers=0 max-size-time=0 max-size-bytes=0 
! mux. 
alsasrc device="$alsadevice" do-timestamp=true 
! audio/x-raw,format=S16LE,rate=48000,channels=2 
! queue 
max-size-buffers=0 max-size-time=0 max-size-bytes=0 
! mux. matroskamux name=mux 
! queue max-size-buffers=0 max-size-time=0 max-size-bytes=0 
! filesink location=$1.mkv

Hope this helps.

However, I have a problem capturing from a VHS VCR. Video is black and white using the S-Video input and no signal using the composite input. Do you have color from VHS (and how)?